# Eunuchs curse/blessings

Tags: customs

Eunuchs demand for money at crossroads/signals/shops/etc. There is fear and people try to avoid their curse. Also some people seek their blessings.

Are there any scriptural references where eunuchs have special powers which make curse or blessings effective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, eunuchs having "special powers" is a recent development or maybe a folkloric belief.

In the scriptures, being a eunuch is taken as more of a curse or deformity, unworthy of any ritualistic rights, since they're thought to be impure or unworthy.

Consider the following verses from scriptures.

### 1. Manusmriti

a. They are ritually impure.

> [Verse 3.239](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200029.html)
>
> चाण्डालश्च वराहश्च कुक्कुटः श्वा तथैव च । रजस्वला च षण्ढश्च
> नैक्षेरन्नश्नतो द्विजान् ॥ २३९ ॥
>
> > 239. The Cāṇdāla, the pig, the cock, as also the dog, the unclean woman and the **eunuch should not look at the Brāhmaṇas while eating.**

- Refer Verse [3.150](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199930.html), and [Verse 3.165](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199946.html) and [Verse 4.205](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200308.html) that consider them being perpetually, ritually defiled and unfit for religious works.

---

b. Not entitled to familial property & heritage, but must be maintained by the family or king, as a dependent.

> [Verse 9.201](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201581.html)
>
> अनंशौ क्लीबपतितौ जात्यन्धबधिरौ तथा । उन्मत्तजडमूकाश्च ये च के
> चिन्निरिन्द्रियाः ॥ २०१ ॥
>
> > 201. **Eunuchs** and outcasts, those born blind or deaf, idiots and the dumb, as well as those deficient in any organ, **are entitled to no
> >      shares.**
>
> English Translation by Ganganath Jha

---

### 2. Mahabharata:

- The epic prohibit their presence near kings, showing again their perceived inefficacy and incapability at Kings council too.

In the Mahabharata [12.83](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826039.html) we get the following excerpt in this regard

> - There should be no dwarfs, no humpbacked persons, no one of an
>   emaciated constitution, no one who is lame or blind, no one who is an
>   idiot, no woman, **and no eunuch, at the spot where the king holds his
>   consultations.**
>
> English Translation by K.M. Ganguli

- The famous curse pronounced on Arjuna by Urvashi to become an eunuch, also shows the term being used to degrade a person, making then being perceived defiled.

---

### Conclusion :

So overall, it looks highly unlikely that the scriptures will discuss eunuchs possessing any "special powers" to bless or curse someone, for the major scriptures (smritis) portray them unfit for religious merits and general lifestyle activities which maybe accorded to a typical biological male or female.

From the viewpoints of the scriptures, it seems more logical to infer that one must avoid their company, at all, lest it leads to impurity, rather than some curse or blessing from them.